# Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.sia.co.id not permitted .not working in android version pie,but working in oreo and all under pie. why?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

```
private String SendAndReceived() {

        HttpURLConnection con = Connector.connect(urlAddress);
        if (con == null) {

            return null;
        }

        try {

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            bw.write(new DataPackager(query).packData());

            bw.flush();

            bw.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            if (responseCode == con.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;

                if (br != null) {

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        response.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                } else {
                    return null;
                }

                br.close();
                is.close();

                return response.toString();


            } else {
                return String.valueOf(responseCode);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

debug:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.yesia.com not permitted
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:115)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:458)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
W/System.err:     at com.yesia.searchrecyclerview.MySQL.SenderReceiver.SendAndReceived(SenderReceiver.java:93)
W/System.err:     at com.yesia.searchrecyclerview.MySQL.SenderReceiver.doInBackground(SenderReceiver.java:51)
W/System.err:     at com.yesia.searchrecyclerview.MySQL.SenderReceiver.doInBackground(SenderReceiver.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an attribute of **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** on application tag in AndroidManifes.xml file.

And also add this.

```
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

**Check [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/protecting-against-unintentional.html) official blog on why this happens and we have to add in the manifest file.**

Comment: Maybe its good focus more on the fact that is about time to switch to https :-)

Comment: Ya. right now all URL support HTTPS but still some Website work on HTTP. So we have to handle it and make sure our application work HTTP API and HTTPS API.

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden wow thank you so much, It's Helping